# How to restore translationX of custom view on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-custom-view, onrestoreinstancestate

I have a custom tab view derived from `LinearLayout` which inflates an xml layout.
Inside it I have a view (`llIndicator`) which is used as an indicator bar and I achive this with animating the `translationX` property of the view like this:

```
val offset = llIndicator.width * activeTabIndex
llIndicator.animate().translationX(offset.toFloat())
```

It all works fine, the only problem is when I am trying to restore the state of the view after activity is destroyed and re-created. Most of the properties does not even need to be saved because the setup code in the fragment is called again, but i would like to save the selected tab and restore the translationX property and restore it without animation.

But I cannot seem to find the correct solution. I save the selected tab to a bundle, successfully restore it, calculate the correct position, but when I set the `translationX` property, it does not do anything...

It does not work if I do it in the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method because it happens before the layout, so I tried to set an `isInstanceBeingRestored` variable to `true` in the `onRestoreInstanceState()` and set `translationX` in the `onLayout()` method, but with no success.

So i tried using an `OnGlobalLayoutListner()` as well by placing the following code in the `init{ }` of the view.

```
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            // Restore view if needed
            if(isInstanceBeingRestored){
               llIndicator.translationX = offset                       
            }
        }
    })
```

It still does nothing... `offset` is correctly calculated, I checked by using `Log.d()`, and also replacing it with by any number has no effect.

So I tried using the post() method, as following:

```
 llIndicator.post({
       llIndicator.translationX = offset
 })
```

I tried placing it in the `onLayout()` method (of course checking the `isInstanceBeingRestored` variable first) and also to the `OnGlobalLayoutListener()` but no effect.

But what is interesting, if I use postDelayed() with a large enough delay, it works.

```
 llIndicator.postDelayed({
       llIndicator.translationX = offset
 }, 1500)
```

But obviously, this solution cannot remain, I just tried it out...
So I am confused... This sounds quite a simple thing to solve but after hours of Googling and trying different codes, and scratching my head, I still couldn't solve it. Surely it cannot be so difficult, can it?

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank's very much  in advance for any help.

**Edit:**

I found something interesting...
If I use `marginStart` instead of `translationX` as below to set the position it works. What would be the reason for that? I don't get it...

```
override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
   if(isInstanceBeingRestored){
        val p = llIndicator.layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams
        p.marginStart = offset.toInt()
        llIndicator.layoutParams = p

        //llIndicator.translationX = offset
   }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Well it only works with `marginStart` if the margin start was 0 before activity gets destroyed... So if I set `offset` to a random value, independent from its previous position, it displays the indicator at the correct position, if `marginStart` was 0 before...
Otherwise the indicator bar appears at the left side of the screen.
Now I am getting really lost...
I double-checked the calculations but they give the correct offset...

Best wishes,
Agoston